# MS Access - Sub Query with Running Total using DSUM with filter

Tags: sql, ms-access

In order to generate running total of Sales Qty in MS Access, I used below query, it is working as expected

```
SELECT ID, [Product Line], DSUM("[Qty]","[SalesData]","[Product Line] like '*Electronics*' AND [ID] <=" & [ID]) AS RunningTotal, FROM SalesData WHERE ([Product Line]) Like '*Electronics*';
```

Now, I need to filter all the record with RunningTotal < 100, 
I ran the below sub query

```
SELECT * FROM( 
SELECT ID, [Product Line], DSUM("[Qty]","[SalesData]","[Product Line] like '*Electronics*' AND [ID] <=" & [ID]) AS RunningTotal, FROM SalesData WHERE ([Product Line]) Like '*Electronics*')
DSUM("[Qty]","[","[Product Line] like '*Electronics*' AND [ID] <=" & [ID]) < 100;
```

It is not working and table is freezed many times while running this query

Data Table

```
ID    Product Line           Qty     RunningTotal
1     Electronics            15            15   
2     R.K. Electricals       20            20
3     Samsung Electronics    10            25
4     Electricals            30            50
5     Electricals            45            95
6     Electronics Components 18            43
7     Electricals            25           120
8     Electronics            50            93
9     Electricals Machines   65           185
10    Electronics            15           108
11    ABC Electronics Ltd    52           160
12    Electricals            15           200
```

Here **RunningTotal** is calculated field (not table field)
Electricals RunningTotal is different and Electronics RunningTotal is different

Expected output for Product Line **like** **Electronics** with RunningTotal < 100

```
ID    Product Line           Qty     RunningTotal
1     Electronics            15            15   
3     Samsung Electronics    10            25
6     Electronics Components 18            43
8     Electronics            50            93
```

Could you please help me to rectify the above query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using domain aggregate functions (such as `DSum`) which are known to be notoriously slow, I would suggest using a correlated subquery, such as the following:

```sql
select q.* from
(
    select t.id, t.[product line], t.qty, 
        (
            select sum(u.qty) 
            from salesdata u 
            where u.[product line] = t.[product line] and u.id <= t.id
        ) as runningtotal
    from salesdata t
    where t.[product line] like "*Electronics*"
) q
where q.runningtotal < 100
```

**EDIT:**

```sql
select t.*, q.runningtotal from salesdata t inner join
(
    select t.id, 
        (
            select sum(u.qty) 
            from salesdata u 
            where u.[product line] like "*Electronics*" and u.id <= t.id
        ) as runningtotal
    from salesdata t
) q on t.id = q.id
where q.runningtotal < 100 and t.[product line] like "*Electronics*"
```

Comment: Above script is not working consistently. Also runningtotal (calculated field) column is empty.  When i run this below query, I am getting wrong result.                                                      select q.* from
(
    select t.id, t.[Product Line], t.[qty], 
        (
            select sum(u.[qty]) 
            from data u 
            where u.[Product Line] = t.[Product Line] and u.id <= t.id
        ) as runningtotal
    from data t
    where t.[Product Line] like "*Electronics*"
) q
where q.runningtotal < 35;

Comment: @RaviKannan I have updated my answer above. Please note that your example output is incorrect since 43+50 = 93 not 83.

Comment: Your updated script is working fine with [Product Line] is exactly Electronics. I would like to get approximate [Product Line] value, that is instead of exactly Electronics It should match with [Product Line] contains Electronics. I changed your above script where q.runningtotal < 100 and t.[product line] like "*Electronics*". I replaced **Equal to** with **Like**, It gave wrong runntingtotal and hence wrong result record. Please suggest me the solution. 

I have updated my above table data and expected result .

Comment: Now your query is working as per my expectation. I appreciate your excellent effort.
One more last query.
Could you please suggest a query to delete the record with product line = "*Electronics*" and runningtotal < 100. I made query **Delete from (**copy above query**)**, it is not working.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark the answer as the solution (and upvote if you feel appropriate), so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are unsure how to do this. Your subsequent query belongs in a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please help me with delete query to delete all the matching records with product line contains "Electronics" and runningtotal < 100.