# Values Disappear when Filtering Correlated Subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, where-clause, correlated-subquery, cumulative-sum

This question is related to the recent answer I provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55050299/7531598).

---

## Setup

Using MS Access 2007.

Assume I have a table called `mytable` consisting of three fields:

- `id` Long Integer AutoNumber (PK)
- `type` Text
- `num` Long Integer

With the following sample data:

```
+----+------+-----+
| id | type | num |
+----+------+-----+
|  1 | A    |  10 |
|  2 | A    |  20 |
|  3 | A    |  30 |
|  4 | B    |  40 |
|  5 | B    |  50 |
|  6 | B    |  60 |
|  7 | C    |  70 |
|  8 | C    |  80 |
|  9 | C    |  90 |
| 10 | D    | 100 |
+----+------+-----+
```

Similar to the linked answer, say I wish to output the three fields, with a running total for each `type` value, with the value of the running total limited to a maximum of `100`, I might use a correlated subquery such as the following:

```sql
select q.* from
(
    select t.id, t.type, t.num, 
        (
            select sum(u.num)
            from mytable u where u.type = t.type and u.id <= t.id
        ) as rt
    from mytable t
) q
where q.rt < 100
```

This produces the expected result:

```
+----+------+-----+----+
| id | type | num | rt |
+----+------+-----+----+
|  1 | A    |  10 | 10 |
|  2 | A    |  20 | 30 |
|  3 | A    |  30 | 60 |
|  4 | B    |  40 | 40 |
|  5 | B    |  50 | 90 |
|  7 | C    |  70 | 70 |
+----+------+-----+----+
```

---

## Observation

Now assume that I wish to filter the result to show only those values for `type like "[AB]"`.

If I use either of the following queries:

```sql
select q.* from
(
    select t.id, t.type, t.num, 
        (
            select sum(u.num)
            from mytable u where u.type = t.type and u.id <= t.id
        ) as rt
    from mytable t
    where t.type like "[AB]"
) q
where q.rt < 100
```

```sql
select q.* from
(
    select t.id, t.type, t.num, 
        (
            select sum(u.num)
            from mytable u where u.type = t.type and u.id <= t.id
        ) as rt
    from mytable t
) q
where q.rt < 100 and q.type like "[AB]"
```

The results are filtered as expected, but the values in the `rt` (running total) column disappear:

```
+----+------+-----+----+
| id | type | num | rt |
+----+------+-----+----+
|  1 | A    |  10 |    |
|  2 | A    |  20 |    |
|  3 | A    |  30 |    |
|  4 | B    |  40 |    |
|  5 | B    |  50 |    |
+----+------+-----+----+
```

---

## Question

Why would the filter cause the values returned by the correlated subquery to disappear?

---

*Thank you for your time reading my question and in advance for any advice you can offer.*

Comment: I don't see value "[AB]" in any record. Using LIKE without * wildcard is really same as = sign. Unless you use pattern matching a range of characters: `type LIKE "[a-b]"`. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Like-Operator-B2F7EF03-9085-4FFB-9829-EEF18358E931

Comment: @June7 Unless I've overlooked something I'm inclined to disagree with you - the pattern `[AB]` when supplied to `like` should match the single characters `A` or `B`.

Comment: Okay, am corrected. Just tested and it works, even in nested query with my data. Will have to do more testing with your data, see what I come up with.

Comment: @June7 Many thanks, I appreciate your input.

Comment: I moved the type criteria to the aggregate subquery and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Moving type criteria to the aggregate subquery works.

One less tier works but the aggregate subquery has to repeat in WHERE clause:

```
SELECT mytable.*, (select sum(u.num)
            from mytable u where u.type = MyTable.type and u.id <= MyTable.id
        ) AS rt
FROM mytable
WHERE ((((select sum(u.num)
            from mytable u where u.type = MyTable.type and u.id <= MyTable.id
        ))<100) AND ((mytable.[type]) Like "[AB]"));
```

An INNER JOIN version:

```
select MyTable.*, q.* from MyTable INNER JOIN
(
    select t.id, t.type, t.num, 
        (
            select sum(u.num)
            from mytable u where u.type = t.type and u.id <= t.id
        ) as rt
    from mytable t
) q
ON q.id=MyTable.ID
where q.rt < 100 AND MyTable.Type LIKE "[AB]";
```

Comment: Thanks @June7, I can confirm that those alternatives return results in the `rt` column and will upvote you for your effort. However, the question remains as to why my original use of the `where` clause causes the values to disappear?