# MS Access - Delete records with runningtotal (sub query output) < 100

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I need to delete records with runningtotal < 100 and [Product Line] contains "Electronics".

Below is Table Data, Here **RunningTotal** is not original field in the table, it is sub query(inner query) output.

```
ID    Product Line           Qty     RunningTotal
1     Electronics            15            15   
2     R.K. Electricals       20            20
3     Samsung Electronics    10            25
4     Electricals            30            50
5     Electricals            45            95
6     Electronics Components 18            43
7     Electricals            25           120
8     Electronics            50            93
9     Electricals Machines   65           185
10    Electronics            15           108
11    ABC Electronics Ltd    52           160
12    Electricals            15           200
```

I used the below query to filter records with [Product Line] contains "Electronics" and runningtotal < 100.

```
select t.*, q.runningtotal from salesdata t inner join
(
    select t.id, 
        (
            select sum(u.qty) 
            from salesdata u 
            where u.[product line] like "*Electronics*" and u.id <= t.id
        ) as runningtotal
    from salesdata t
) q on t.id = q.id
where q.runningtotal < 100 and t.[product line] like "*Electronics*"
```

I copied the matched records (based on above query) into another that table, that is working.
Once I copied, I need to delete the records that are matched (*[Product Line] contains "Electronics" and runningtotal < 100*). I wrote below query, It throws error **can not delete from specified table** and not working

```
delete from (
select t.*, q.runningtotal from salesdata t inner join
(
    select t.id, 
        (
            select sum(u.qty) 
            from salesdata u 
            where u.[product line] like "*Electronics*" and u.id <= t.id
        ) as runningtotal
    from salesdata t
) q on t.id = q.id
where q.runningtotal < 100 and t.[product line] like "*Electronics*")
```

Your help will be very much appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure of the rules regarding accreditation on SO, but FWIW, original code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55050299/7531598).

Answer (score 1):

You might try:

```
delete from salesdata sd
    where sd2.[product line] like "*Electronics*" and
          (select sum(sd2.qty)
           from salesdata as sd2
           where sd2.[product line] like "*Electronics*" and
                 sd2.id < sd.id
          ) < 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, the `DELETE` must specify a table not a query. Assuming you saved the `SELECT` query (which you *should* have for engine to compile best execution plan) consider an `EXISTS` clause with subquery.

```
delete from salesdata s
where exists (select 1 from mysavedquery mq where s.id = mq.id)
```